# fftw + opencv inconsistent output

Tags: c++, opencv, fft, fftw, dft

I recently tried to implement an FFT function for Opencv's Mat.
I inspired my implementation mainly from FFTW's code samples and from :
[FFTW-OpenCV](https://github.com/marwan-abdellah/FFTW-OpenCV/blob/master/FFT_CV.cxx)

I payed close attention to adapt the size of the input image in order to fasten the processing.
It seems that I did something wrong because the output is always a black image.

Here is my implementation:

```
void fft2_32f(const cv::Mat1f& _src, cv::Mat2f& dst)
    {

        cv::Mat2f src;

        const int rows = cv::getOptimalDFTSize(_src.rows);
        const int cols = cv::getOptimalDFTSize(_src.cols);

    //    const int total = cv::alignSize(rows*cols,steps);


        if(_src.isContinuous() && _src.rows == rows && _src.cols == cols)
        {

            src = cv::Mat2f::zeros(src.size());
            dst = cv::Mat2f::zeros(src.size());

            // 1) copy the source into a complex matrix (the imaginary component  is set to 0).

            cblas_scopy(src.total(), _src.ptr<float>(), 1, src.ptr<float>(), 2);

            // 2) prepare and apply the transform.

            fftwf_complex* ptr_in = reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(src.ptr<float>());
            fftwf_complex* ptr_out = reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(dst.ptr<float>());

    //        fftwf_plan fft = fftwf_plan_dft_1d(src.total(), ptr_in, ptr_out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
            fftwf_plan fft = fftwf_plan_dft_2d(src.rows, src.cols, ptr_in, ptr_out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

            fftwf_execute(fft);
            fftwf_destroy_plan(fft);

            // 3) normalize

            cblas_saxpy(dst.rows * dst.step1(), 1.f/dst.total(), dst.ptr<float>(), 1, dst.ptr<float>(), 1);

        }
        else
        {

            src = cv::Mat2f::zeros(rows, cols);
            dst = cv::Mat2f::zeros(rows, cols);

            // 1) copy the source into a complex matrix (the imaginary component  is set to 0).

            support::parallel_for(cv::Range(0, _src.rows), [&src, &_src](const cv::Range& range)->void
            {

                for(int r=range.start; r<range.end; r++)
                {
                    int c=0;

                    const float* it_src = _src[r];
                    float* it_dst = src.ptr<float>(r);

    #if CV_ENABLE_UNROLLED
                    for(;c<=_src.cols-4; c+=4, it_src+=4, it_dst+=8)
                    {
                        *it_dst = *it_src;
                        *(it_dst+2) = *(it_src+1);
                        *(it_dst+4) = *(it_src+2);
                        *(it_dst+6) = *(it_src+3);
                    }
    #endif
                    for(; c<_src.cols; c++, it_src++, it_dst+=2)
                        *it_dst = *it_src;
                }   
            }, 0x80);

            // 2) prepare and apply the transform.

            fftwf_complex* ptr_in = reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(src.ptr<float>());
            fftwf_complex* ptr_out = reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(dst.ptr<float>());

            fftwf_plan fft = fftwf_plan_dft_2d(src.rows, src.cols, ptr_in, ptr_out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

            fftwf_execute(fft);
            fftwf_destroy_plan(fft);

            double min(0.);
            double max(0.);

            // 3) normalize

            cblas_saxpy(dst.rows * dst.step1(), 1.f/dst.total(), dst.ptr<float>(), 1, dst.ptr<float>(), 1);

        }    
    }
```

Note:

The `parallel_for` implementation is inspired by: [How to use lambda as a parameter to parallel_for_](http://answers.opencv.org/question/65800/how-to-use-lambda-as-a-parameter-to-parallel_for_/)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does the continuous version work? Does it work if you remove the normalization, or right after `fftw_execute`? There are so many ways to debug this…

Comment: Actually the fft is in both case apply on a continuous data. In the first case if the image size fit with the optimum DFT dimensions it's faster to copy the datas into the complex matrix. 
But non of them does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out my issue.
This function written as is does work perfectly (at least for the purpose I made it for).
My issue was that :

```
cv::Mat dst = cv::Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_32FC2);

cv::Mat1f srcw = src;
cv::Mat1f dstw = dst;

fft2_32f(srcw, dstw); // realocate dstw to the optimal size for receive the output depending on the size of srcw. ... so the dstw is reallocate but not dst.

dst.copyTo(_outputVariable);
```

In that case the correct information is store in dstw but not in dst because of the reallocation inside the function.
So when I try to visualize my data I had a black image because of that.

The proper call use to be:

```
cv::Mat dst;

cv::Mat1f srcw = src;
cv::Mat1f dstw;

fft2_32f(srcw, dstw); // realocate dstw to the optimal size for receive the output depending on the size of srcw. ... so the dstw is reallocate but not dst.

dst = dstw;

dst.copyTo(_outputVariable); // or dstw.copyTo(_outputVariable);
```

With that code I got the proper output.

Note depending on the application a roi (take a look to the operator()(const cv::Rect&) of OpenCV's Mat container) corresponding to the size of the input may be usefull in order to preserve the dimensions.

Thank you for your help :).

Can someone help me to mark this topic as close ? please.